# Handle browser alert/pop up in Robot framework + appium

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, python-appium

I am downloading an .apk file from a link.

I open browser > Go to URL > Chrome browser is displayed.

How do I click on "OK" from the alert.

I am using AppiumLibrary.

Comment: You can Use `Click Text   OK` .

Answer (score 0):

capabilities.setCapability(“autoAcceptAlerts”,true);